# Nameservers at the registrar - circular logic?

Tags: dns

Simple question, really, but one for which Google doesn't return many useful answers.

If I register a domain (www.thing.com) and want to use two custom nameservers - ns1.thing.com and ns2.thing.com - how does anything discover the IPs to which those addresses are configured to point when it's only those servers that contain that information?

Shouldn't the domain registry require IP addresses when specifying nameservers?

Comment: The term you want to google for is "glue record".

Answer (score 0):

ns2.thing.com and ns1.thing.com are A records themselves or CNAME's pointing to an A record, so they always resolve to a IP-address.

Cheers,

Niek